# Laurent series of a function around $t=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am trying to solve the contour integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{e^{t}}{t(2at+x^2)}{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{ax^2}{2(2at+x^2)}\right)\,{\rm d}t
$$

where the path of integration $C$ starts at $-\infty-i0$ on the
real axis, goes to $-\varepsilon-i0$, circles the origin in the
counterclockwise direction with radius $\varepsilon$ to the point
$-\varepsilon+i0$ and returns to the point $-\infty+i0$ (I got
such path from Hankel's contour integral of reciprocal Gamma
function $1/\Gamma(z)$).

I concluded that a given function
has two poles: First one is $t=0$ and I also calculated the
residual in that pole and it is equal to $\frac{e^{a/2}}{x^2}$;
second one is at $t=-\frac{x^2}{2a}$ and I need to express a given
function as a Laurent series and find a coefficient $c_{-1}$ which
will be a residual... In order to do that first I used
substitution $2at+x^2=y$ so then I can express my function around
$t=0$:
\begin{align*}\frac{2a*{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{-x^2}{2a}\right)*{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{y}{2a}\right)*{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{ax^2}{2y}\right)}{-x^2y\left(1-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)}&=
\frac{-2a*{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{-x^2}{2a}\right)}{x^2y}\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)^n\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{\left(\frac{y}{2a}\right)^m}{m!}
\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{\left(\frac{ax^2}{2y}\right)^k}{k!}\\&=\frac{-2a*{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{-x^2}{2a}\right)}{x^2}\sum_{n,m,k\ge0}\dfrac{y^{n+m-k-1}(ax^2)^k}{x^{2n}(2a)^m2^km!k!}\end{align*}

Please can you help me to find the desired coefficient...

Comment: Is $x$ a real number? In this case, if $a>0$, then $-x^2/2a$ is on $C$ unless you assume $\varepsilon>x^2/2a$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a real number and also $a>0$ but I don't know what to do then?

Comment: A pole cannot be on the countourn $C$, thus you must assume $\varepsilon>x^2/2a$.

Comment: Tnx. And, please, do you know how to calculate the appropriate residual in that case?

Comment: Sorry, it's quite difficult your integral. A more `appropiated' countour integral would be replacing $C$ by $-C$, that is, $C$ starts in $-\infty+i0$, goes to $\varepsilon+0i$, makes the circle and then goes back to $-\infty+i0$. In that case, if we take $0<\varepsilon <x^/2a$, we obtain that the second pole is not inside the countourn and then it is not necessary to compute its resudue. I hope this helps you, though it is not an answer for your question.